# unable to convert rest api json to dart object

Tags: flutter

after converting the rest api response using jsondecode not able to loop through it

i have rest api from laravel backend, i am try to consumed by flutter app.
after converting the response using jsondecode not able to loop through it and make an list to be used in widget view

api Json response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "mobile_num": "34567",
            "date_before": "2018-12-20 00:00:00",
            "cargo_id": 3,
            "weight": 12,
            "description": "medical stoer",
            "country_id": 22,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2018-12-25 10:42:35",
            "updated_at": "2018-12-25 10:42:35"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user_id": 3,
            "mobile_num": "21345",
            "date_before": "2018-12-12 00:00:00",
            "cargo_id": 3,
            "weight": 3,
            "description": "welcome by the",
            "country_id": 3,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2018-12-25 10:43:02",
            "updated_at": "2018-12-25 10:43:02"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "user_id": 2,
            "mobile_num": "2342344543",
            "date_before": "2018-12-12 00:00:00",
            "cargo_id": 5,
            "weight": 44,
            "description": "hello maseer",
            "country_id": 3,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2018-12-25 10:44:16",
            "updated_at": "2018-12-25 10:44:16"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Senders retrieved successfully"
}
```

http get response code:

```
  Future<dynamic> _getData(String url) async {
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    return data;
  }

 Future<List<Sender>> getSenders() async {
    var data = await _getData(_baseUrl);
    List<dynamic> sendersData = data['data'];
    print(sendersData);
    print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    //code stop in this point not loop through sendersData***********
    List<Sender> senders =
        sendersData.map((s) => Sender.fromMap(s)).toList();
    print("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
    print(senders);
    // print(senders.length);
    return senders;
  }
```

model code:

```
class Sender {
  String id,
      userId,
      mobileNum,
      dateBefore,
      cargoId,
      weightS,
      descriptionS,
      countryId,
      createdAt;
  Sender({
    this.id,
    this.userId,
    this.mobileNum,
    this.dateBefore,
    this.cargoId,
    this.weightS,
    this.descriptionS,
    this.countryId,
    this.createdAt,
  });

  Sender.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    userId = map['user_id'];
    mobileNum = map['mobile_num'];
    dateBefore = map['date_before'];
    cargoId = map['cargo_id'];
    weightS = map['weight'];
    descriptionS = map['description'];
    countryId = map['country_id'];
    createdAt = map['created_at'];
  }
}
```

this code not execute : List senders =
        sendersData.map((s) => Sender.fromJson(s)).toList();

no return to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id,userId, etc. is an integer value, not a string.

```
    class Sender {
  int id;
  int userId;
  String mobileNum;
  String dateBefore;
  int cargoId;
  int weight;
  String description;
  int countryId;
  String deletedAt;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  Sender(
      {this.id,
      this.userId,
      this.mobileNum,
      this.dateBefore,
      this.cargoId,
      this.weight,
      this.description,
      this.countryId,
      this.deletedAt,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  Sender.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    userId = json['user_id'];
    mobileNum = json['mobile_num'];
    dateBefore = json['date_before'];
    cargoId = json['cargo_id'];
    weight = json['weight'];
    description = json['description'];
    countryId = json['country_id'];
    deletedAt = json['deleted_at'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['user_id'] = this.userId;
    data['mobile_num'] = this.mobileNum;
    data['date_before'] = this.dateBefore;
    data['cargo_id'] = this.cargoId;
    data['weight'] = this.weight;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['country_id'] = this.countryId;
    data['deleted_at'] = this.deletedAt;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
flutter: [{id: 1, user_id: 1, mobile_num: 34567, date_before: 2018-12-20 00:00:00, cargo_id: 3, weight: 12, description: medical stoer, country_id: 22, deleted_at: null, created_at: 2018-12-25 10:42:35, updated_at: 2018-12-25 10:42:35}, {id: 2, user_id: 3, mobile_num: 21345, date_before: 2018-12-12 00:00:00, cargo_id: 3, weight: 3, description: welcome by the, country_id: 3, deleted_at: null, created_at: 2018-12-25 10:43:02, updated_at: 2018-12-25 10:43:02}, {id: 3, user_id: 2, mobile_num: 2342344543, date_before: 2018-12-12 00:00:00, cargo_id: 5, weight: 44, description: hello maseer, country_id: 3, deleted_at: null, created_at: 2018-12-25 10:44:16, updated_at: 2018-12-25 10:44:16}]
flutter: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
flutter: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
flutter: [Instance of 'Sender', Instance of 'Sender', Instance of 'Sender']
```

Comment: It would improve your answer if you also parsed the `DateTime`s

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed A it work by change the field from string to int as the api,

Comment: @RichardHeap could you please explain how to parse `DateTime`fields

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are creating a list of maps is wrong in your getSenders method. I will comment the lines that you need replace and put some code that will work.
Make sure that you are handling the right data types inside your Sender.fromMap(...) method too.

```
Future<List<Sender>> getSenders() async {
var data = await _getData(_baseUrl);
//List<dynamic> sendersData = data['data']; // replace this line with
List< Map<String, dynamic> > sendersData = List.from( data['data'] );
print(sendersData);
print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
List<Sender> senders = sendersData.map((s) => Sender.fromMap(s)).toList();

print("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
print(senders);
// print(senders.length);
return senders;
```

}